# I have a Zenfone 6 unusable because of a broken screen, and a HTC one m9 with a broken power button. Is there a way I could use one of them?

Tags: htc, buttons, power-on

The touch screen on the zenfone6 is unusable because it presses randomly.

I tried to connect it to my pc and use scrcpy to control it, but it doesn't detect it.

adb doesn't detect it.

I used to be able to use the htc one m9 by waking it by double tapping it, but right now the battery is dead. I charged it, but I can't turn it on. adb doesn't detect it

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Zenfone is working? try to enable adb. otg keyboard may help. regarding htc try to simultaneously press vol keys and connect usb cable, maybe there is a way to reboot from recovery

Comment: adb cannot detect the zenfone. I dont have a way to connect a keyboard to the zenfone (no usb c adapter). Pressing the volume keys on the htc while connecting doesn't do anything. Thanks

Comment: Try the lighter ignition trick

Comment: Isn't it just for screens with deadzones? Mine registers false inputs